# MoonMail Deployment Issues

Tags: moonmail

I have been trying to get the MoonMail program (https://github.com/microapps/MoonMail/) working on a EC2 Ubuntu 16.04 server I set up, but I cannot quite seem to get past the "sls function deploy" stage.

I believe I have managed to deploy the resources, barring 8 tables due to our accounts limitation on DynamoDB tables (I believe I read that this should not matter for the time being, as it seems these would only be used for function invocation).

When I run the "sls function deploy" command, I get the following warnings:

```
Serverless: Deploying the specified functions in "dev" to the following regions: eu-west-1
Serverless: / Serverless: WARNING: This variable is not defined: esHost
Serverless: WARNING: This variable is not defined: esRegion
Serverless: - Serverless: WARNING: This variable is not defined: iotEndpoint
Serverless: | Serverless: WARNING: This variable is not defined: redisEndpointPort
Serverless: WARNING: This variable is not defined: redisEndpointAddress
Serverless: WARNING: This variable is not defined: redisPassword
Serverless: - Serverless: WARNING: This variable is not defined: iotEndpoint
Serverless: | Serverless: WARNING: This variable is not defined: unsubscribedCallbackUrl
Serverless: / ^C
```

I feel like these at this point do not matter, but I am not sure and cannot find any other answers to this end. I have permissions to create these if required.

Regardless, the program at this point does not fail, but it does seem to run for a very long time (~1hr 30mins). Perhaps this is expected, but it seemed longer than I anticipated so assumed something had gone awry. I could not see any changes in my AWS account, other than my _meta/_tmp folder becoming very large on the server (> 1GB).

The variables used for this stage in _meta/variables/ were:

```
{
    "defaultRegion": "eu-west-1",
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "stage": "dev",
    "defaultRCU": 2,
    "defaultWCU": 2,
    "sentEmailsRCU": 2,
    "sendEmailsWCU": 2,
    "scheduledAtIndexRCU": 2,
    "scheduledAtIndexWCU": 2,
    "scheduledCampaignsRCU": 2,
    "scheduledCampaignsWCU": 2,
    "clicksRCU": 2,
    "clicksReportRCU": 2,
    "clicksReportWCU": 2,
    "clicksWCU": 2,
    "opensRCU": 2,
    "opensReportRCU": 2,
    "opensReportWCU": 2,
    "opensWCU": 2,
    "recipientsRCU": 2,
    "recipientsWCU": 2,
    "apiHost": "mydomain.com",
    "defaultEmailAddress": "me@mydomain.com",
    "defaultFromName": "myName"
}
```

Is the time delay here expected? The EC2 server I am using is just a micro, so this could account for the slowness. Any guidance would be appreciated as I am a bit stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If resources are correctly deployed, I would try deploying a single function to see if it works. Serverless is not really efficient when deploying a bunch of functions at once (at least version `0.5`)